# Setting up gradle azurewebapp plugin for springboot deployment

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, azure-java-tools

I have a springboot webapp that i want to deploy to Azure. The app is springboot jar. I have been able to use `azurewebapp` plug in to achieve this but it is using `OAUTH2` which limits integrating this deployment method into our CD (bitbucket).

So the more generic question would be how can i deploy my springboot app via bitbucket deployment pipeline?

I looked at sample yaml file from bitbucket and it looks like that it needs these variables

```
AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
AZURE_APP_NAME: $AZURE_APP_NAME
ZIP_FILE: app-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip
```

So where would i get these values from

- Azure App ID: I am assuming this is from Azure app service? But i don't see any app-id on my currently deployed app.
- Azure Password: is this password for my (admin) account?
- Azure Tenant ID: Whats this? where to get it from?

Also, is this correct approach or should i be using some other method? Azure pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

`Azure_App_Id`, `Azure_Password`, `Azure_Tenant_Id` are the key-value pairs you will get after creating the service principal for your application in the Azure.

***Brief Explanation:***

- **`AZURE_APP_ID`** is the associated service principal's application Id/Name/URL for login.
- **`AZURE_PASSWORD`** is the service principal creds

As you mentioned the bitbucket pipeline, this [bitbucket official site](https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-functions-deploy/src/master/README.md) will helps you how to create service principal for your web app and get the details required for deploying ***YAML*** script.

This site extends to [Azure CLI site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli) of creating service principal that is focused on Function app deploy script to bitbucket, where you can follow the same steps and replace the function app with web app.